# How I can check if an error occurs with Async-await in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Whilst developing in node.js I came across with async-await especially with these examples:

- Without Async function: https://gist.github.com/robogeek/110428f0ac772bdbfd62ae4024f42b1b#file-readfortunesbeforeasyncfunctions-mjs

```
function readFortunesBeforeAsyncFunctions(callback) {
   const fortunesfn = process.env.FORTUNE_FILE;
   fs.readFile(fortunesfn, 'utf8', (err, fortunedata) => {
       // errors and results land here
       // errors are handled in a very unnatural way
       if (err) {
           callback(err);
       } else {
          // Further asynchronous processing is nested here
           fortunes = fortunedata.split('\n%\n').slice(1);
           callback();
       }
   });
   // This is the natural place for results to land
   // Throwing exceptions is the natural method to report errors
}
```

- With Async function: https://gist.github.com/robogeek/ead3a54c56a8447015adc4d993d7b738#file-read-fortunes-mjs

```
import fs from 'fs-extra';

let fortunes;

async function readFortunes() {
    const fortunesfn = process.env.FORTUNE_FILE;
    const fortunedata = await fs.readFile(fortunesfn, 'utf8');
    fortunes = fortunedata.split('\n%\n').slice(1);
}

export default async function() {
    if (!fortunes) {
        await readFortunes();
    }
    if (!fortunes) {
        throw new Error('Could not read fortunes');
    }
    let f = fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
    return f;
};
```

In both cases the autor (`robogeek`) tries to read a fortune file and show random fortunes. In the callback approach, the callback provided via the `fs.read` has the `err` as first argument, per common javascript coding convention, so we can check the error by peeking the value offered via the argument.

If `err`'s value is null then all green and no error has occured.

On the async approach how I can handle if any error occurs, especially in api's that utilize callbacks to pass around the error, for example using the mandrill api:

```
var mandrill = require('node-mandrill')('ThisIsMyDummyApiKey');

const sendEmail = async () => {

mandrill('/messages/send', {
    message: {
        to: [{email: 'git@jimsc.com', name: 'Jim Rubenstein'}],
        from_email: 'you@domain.com',
        subject: "Hey, what's up?",
        text: "Hello, I sent this message using mandrill."
    }
}, function(error, response)
{
    //uh oh, there was an error
    if (error) console.log( JSON.stringify(error) );

    //everything's good, lets see what mandrill said
    else console.log(response);
});

}

/**
 * How I Need to refactor my method in order to handle errors with the following piece of code?
*/
await sendEmail()
```

Comment: both link leads to the same async function

Comment: Ok Fixed it and it looks into the fdifferent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an async function, you can call your function like this:

```
async ()=>{ try { await someAsynchronousFunction() } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
```

As you can see by encapsulating your asynchronous function call in a try/catch block you can gain access to any errors that occur while executing and awaiting a response.

By the way your gists and stuff are basically copied twice.

Comment: So in my case with mandrill, will it be like that? https://gist.github.com/pc-magas/580e023f2c0a5c4cd8c1e41706a4fb03

Comment: It should except I would instead of directly returning the awaited mandril response, I would call that in a try/catch and then return the result inside the try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution is to return a Promise from your async function.
Your code will look like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs-extra';

let fortunes;

async function readFortunes() {
    const fortunesfn = process.env.FORTUNE_FILE;
    const fortunedata = await fs.readFile(fortunesfn, 'utf8');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fortunedata.split('\n%\n').slice(1));
}

export default async function() {
    await readFortunes()
        .then(data => { return fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)]; }, 
            err => throw new Error('Could not read fortunes', err)
    );

};
```

Comment: On the then callback ` data => { return fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];` I assume the data parameter contains the returned data and the fortunes is just an empty array.

Comment: That's true. The data parameter contains the results of the `readFortunes()` method